# How to list all forced query plans and cancel one

Tags: sql-server, ssms, execution-plan, sql-server-2016, query-store

Using SSMS 2016 Query Store I forced a few weeks ago a specific query to use a specific plan. Now every now and then I have the error:

> Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN

I assume `SET FORCEPLAN` is passed automatically since the code executing that query doesn't.
So I would like to review my forced plan, maybe cancel it. But I can't find that query in the query store anymore.

Hence my question: is there a way to list all forced query plans and then how can I cancel one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to get information about 'forced' plans by querying this catalog view ([sys.query_store_plan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn818155.aspx)) filtering on **is_forced_plan = 1**.  At the bottom of the page are links to other useful catalog views for Query Store.

This stored procedure ([sp_query_store_unforce_plan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn818154.aspx)) allows you to 'unforce' a plan.

Comment: Spot on, thanks! Actually I also just discovered by chance it's possible to search by query text using the magnifier in: Query Store -> Tracked Queries